Anchor framework, validation failed
Writing the IDL file
Writing the .ts file
Build success
Error: package section not provided

When I tried to verify, anchor verify 9nvhTP4tjhR2qRt4QkPCcGhE8jtzRbbgRBggPrrNxhEH
When I perform validation in the root directory of the project, I get an error
Error: package section not provided
I deployed to devnet. It has been successfully deployed. https://explorer.solana.com/address/CirTw1apKgQHSveAvpMp3P283Z54XzJWTBy1LHVLz7E9?cluster=devnet
I haven't made any changes to the code. I entered the programs/pharmacy-guard-contract because its Cargo.toml has a [package] section.
I closed the previous program ID and rebuilt and deployed a new program ID.
I tried to re verify, but unfortunately.
anchor verify CirTw1apKgQHSveAvpMp3P283Z54XzJWTBy1LHVLz7E9 --skip-build
Error: Binaries don't match

When I tried to verify again, it turned into various error. I have never even seen this pubkey before. I don't know which account it's referring to
Error: AccountNotFound: pubkey=6PnPLX93mScpxXYXwGWswcnSWaJti7S2ToZt88s5m1i7

Caused by:
    AccountNotFound: pubkey=6PnPLX93mScpxXYXwGWswcnSWaJti7S2ToZt88s5m1i7

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0): error trying to connect: tls handshake eof

Caused by:
    RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0): error trying to connect: tls handshake eof

cxp@CXPfromR9000P:~/solana_learn/solana-radar-hackathon/pharma-guard-contract$ anchor deploy --verifiable
Deploying cluster: https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0
Upgrade authority: /home/cxp/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "pharma_guard_contract"...
Program path: /home/cxp/solana_learn/solana-radar-hackathon/pharma-guard-contract/target/verifiable/pharma_guard_contract.so...
Program Id: CirTw1apKgQHSveAvpMp3P283Z54XzJWTBy1LHVLz7E9

Deploy success

The execution was successful, but https://explorer.solana.com/address/CirTw1apKgQHSveAvpMp3P283Z54XzJWTBy1LHVLz7E9/verified-build?cluster=devnet Still showing as unverified.

This means the anchor verify built the program successfully but the deployed program at the address does not match the program built locally. Probably good to check what program you have deployed on-chain.

I deployed to devnet. It has been successfully deployed. I haven't made any changes to the code. I entered the programs/pharmacy-guard-contract because its Cargo.toml has a [package] section.

Then it may depend on where you deployed from maybe? You need to deploy verifiable build. When you build with --verifiable  then the output program is available at target/verifiable/. The anchor deploy deploys from target/deploy which could be a different binary. Have you used anchor deploy --verifiable?
See https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/issues/2167

Or I produce verifiable build with anchor and then manually deploy. My steps are pasted here: https://github.com/marinade-finance/validator-bonds?tab=readme-ov-file#contract-deployment

I don't know which command was executed, but there are indeed files in my target/verifiable directory. But when performing anchor verify, there is none.

`
cxp@CXPfromR9000P:~/solana_learn/solana-radar-hackathon/pharma-guard-contract$ anchor deploy --verifiable
Deploying cluster: https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0
Upgrade authority: /home/cxp/.config/solana/id.json
Deploying program "pharma_guard_contract"...
Program path: /home/cxp/solana_learn/solana-radar-hackathon/pharma-guard-contract/target/verifiable/pharma_guard_contract.so...
Program Id: CirTw1apKgQHSveAvpMp3P283Z54XzJWTBy1LHVLz7E9
Deploy success`
The execution was successful, but explorer.solana Still showing as unverified.

Yes, I need to investigate more on solana explorer thingy. I will be happy when you share your experience how to do that :-)
The thing is that is a different verification than the one with Anchor. You need to build and somehow upload(?) somewhere. See info here: https://github.com/Ellipsis-Labs/solana-verifiable-build/

Yes, I used the tutorial in Anchor and did not verify successfully. I am trying to use the ellipsis tutorial you provided to give it a try.

I'm sorry, buddy. I tried the GitHub/Ellis Labs/Solana verifiable build you sent me. But it's just too complicated to explain. I would prefer to use the anchor's built-in program to complete the verification.
